# Selenium: List outgoing URLs in a page

Tags: javascript, dom, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to make a list of the all the outgoing URLs in some page.

For simplification let's assume that only `<a>` elements can produce links.

For some of the  elements the URL is in the `href` attribute and for others the URL is generated by javascript when the user clicks them.

My solution is to find all the `<a>` elements in the page, and then click them one by one.
When I click an outgoing link, the browser navigates to that link. In order to keep clicking the rest of the links, I navigate back to the original page.
However, when I navigate back to the original page, I get:
`org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`.

My code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers/chromedriver.exe")
val driver = new ChromeDriver()

val byHref = By.tagName("a")

// Get all <a> elements
val links = driver.findElements(byHref)

// Resolve all <a> to URLs
val resolvedLinks = links.map(resolveLink(_))

// Resolve <a> to URL
def resolveLink(link: WebElement) : String = {
  // Get href attribute
  val href = link.getAttribute("href")

  // href is javascript?
  if (href == null || href.startsWith("javascript:")) {
    // Click link
    link.click()

    // Get the URL we navigated to
    val navigatedUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl

    // Navigate back to our original page
    driver.navigate().back()

    navigatedUrl 
  }
  else
    href
}
```

My question is: is there a way to list all the outgoing URLs in a page while maintaining the original context of the page?

Answer (score 3):

As soon as you navigate to another web-page, or even switch into an `iframe` in the same web-page, any `WebElement` object that you have in memory is potentially "stale".

One optional solution, is to list down all the element IDs, and then iterate that list instead.

It is unclear to me what language you're using, but here is how you can do it in Java:

```
Set<String> linkIds = new HashSet<String>();
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
for (WebElement link : links)
{
    linkIds.add(link.getAttribute("id"));
}
for (String linkId : linkIds)
{
    WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.id(linkId));
    link.click();
    // Add the rest of your code here...
}
```

Please note, however, that all the above is under the assumption that each link has a unique ID, and that all the links remain in the web-page when you navigate back into it. If this is not the case in the specific web-pages that you are accessing, then an alternative approach is required here.

Instead of iterating the link-IDs, you can iterate the link-indexes, assuming that the links **remain in the same order** when you navigate in and out of the web-page. This is somewhat less efficient though, because you have to retrieve the entire list of all the links at the beginning of each iteration.

```
for (int i=0; true; i++)
{
    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    if (i >= links.size())
        break;
    links.get(i).click();
    // Add the rest of your code here...
}
```

The code above should work **even if the links do not remain in the same order** when you navigate back into the web-page. However, under such scenario, you will most likely miss out on some of them.